# Truncate dynamic string javascript

Tags: javascript, string, instagram, truncate

I am using the instafeed.js plugin to dynamically generate a photo feed.
I'd like to truncate the photo comments to 140 characters or so, but I'm having issues doing it. I'm generating my markup via the instafeed script, and it is putting the photo comments into a div with the class "instacomments". I've written another function to try and truncate the string within any element with the instacomments class, but it's not working.

Instafeed script:

```
window.onload = function pullPhotos(){

  var routeFeed = new Instafeed({
    get: 'tagged',
    tagName: 'Route91Harvest',
    clientId: 'myID',
    limit: '18',
    resolution: 'low_resolution',
    template: '<div class="col-md-4 instapad"><div class="instacontainer heightlimit"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-12 imageblock whitebg"><a href="{{link}}"><img src="http:{{image}}" class="img-responsive center-block" /></a></div></div><div class="row"><div class="col-md-12 whitebg"><div class="instacomments center-block">{{caption}}</div></div></div></div></div>'
  });

  var rtFeed = new Instafeed({
    get: 'tagged',
    tagName: 'Rt91Harvest',
    clientId: 'myID',
    limit: '18',
    resolution: 'low_resolution',
    template: '<div class="col-md-4 instapad"><div class="instacontainer heightlimit"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-12 imageblock whitebg"><a href="{{link}}"><img src="http:{{image}}" class="img-responsive center-block" /></a></div></div><div class="row"><div class="col-md-12 whitebg"><div class="instacomments center-block">{{caption}}</div></div></div></div></div>'
  });

  routeFeed.run();
  rtFeed.run();

}
```

And here is my truncate script, which does not work currently:

```
function short(length) {
    var s = document.getElementsByClassName('instacomments');
    var len = s.length;

    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
       var g = s[i].innerHTML;
       var x = ". . . More";
       var leng = length-5;
       var html = g.substring(0, leng)+"";
       var allHTML = html+x;
       s[i].innerHTML = allHTML;
    }

}
short(140);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're never testing whether `g.length > leng`.  Why not?  Are you aware that `&nbsp;` specifies one user-visible character in the HTML, but takes up 6 in the string?  Might there be tags in the string that take up space but specify no user-visible characters?  Are you concerned about truncating a tag: `short('<h1>', 3) == '<h1. . . More'`?

Comment: You've got just plain `length` where you probably want `g.length`.

Comment: Not sure where you are seeing the &nbsp; and this script was one i found on another search that had successful results, so i'm trying to tweak it to work for my purposes. Honestly I plan on getting rid of the "...More" stuff once I can figure out the truncation part

Answer (score 0):

I would separate out truncation logic so it can be more generic

```
function trunc(str, max_length, suffix, margin) {
    max_length = max_length | 0;
    margin = margin | 0;
    if (max_length <= 0 || str.length <= max_length + margin)
        return str;
    if (undefined === suffix || null === suffix)
        suffix = '';
    return str.slice(0, max_length) + suffix;
}
```

Then have the loop like this

```
function short(length) {
    var s = document.getElementsByClassName('instacomments');
    var i = s.length;

    while (i--) {
        s[i].innerHTML = trunc(s[i].innerHTML, length - 5, ". . . More", 5);
    }
}
short(140);
```

---

Example to demonstrate what the parameters of my *function* `trunc` do

```
trunc('12345'  , 5, '…', 0);  //  "12345"
trunc('123456' , 5, '…', 0);  //  "12345…"
trunc('123456' , 5, '…', 1);  //  "123456"
trunc('1234567', 5, '…', 1);  //  "12345…"
```

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work. I've copied and pasted this and added to my window onload function, and it isn't working. @paul